# Entity Framework Core 2.1, ChangeTracker.Tracked

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out how to use Entity Framework Cores 2.1 new *ChangeTracker.Tracked Event* to hook into reading queries. Unfortunately, I'm not being able to understand how to implement this. 
Since it's a new feature it's not possible to find any articles on it and the official Microsoft docs site does not provide any help or sample code. 
My scenario is pretty simple. I have a database with following columns:
*id, customerId, metadata.* 
When a user queries this table I want to intercept the query result set and for every row, I want to compare the customerId with currently logged in user. 
I'm hoping that *ChangeTracker.Tracked Event* can help me in intercepting the return result set. I'm looking for some sample code on how to achieve above.

Comment: I think the event arguments are pretty obvious - a `bool` property indicating whether it originates from query or user operation like `Attach`, and `EntityEntry` containing the entity, state etc. The question is what actually are you trying to do - *compare the customerId with current logged in user*, and then what?

Comment: If it was pretty obvious I wouldn't be asking it here. I find it sad that you are ruining my question by making it seem stupid and not answering it, but rather asking me to elaborate on something that is not needed in order to neither understand or answer my question. I would unfortunately ask you to go some  else thread.

Comment: That wasn't the intent of my comment and your question *definitely is **not** stupid* (sorry if you are reading it that way). The whole purpose of the previous comment was to clarify what to do after the comparison (if the customerId equals/not equals to the currently logged in user). The possible answer depends on that, because instead of the event in question the [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) might be more appropriate.

Comment: The comparison will return either true/false. Global query filters cannot be used to intercept result-set of queries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a sample usage of the `ChangeTracker.Tracked` event.

Add the following method to your context (requires `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;`):

```cs
void OnEntityTracked(object sender, EntityTrackedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FromQuery && e.Entry.Entity is YourEntityClass)
    {
        var entity = (YourEntityClass)e.Entry.Entity;
        bool isCurrentUser = entity.customerId == CurrentUserId;
            // do something (not sure what)
    }
}
```

and attach it to the `ChangeTracker.Tracked` even in your context constructor:

```cs
ChangeTracker.Tracked += OnEntityTracked;
```

As described in the `Tracked` event [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.tracked?view=efcore-2.1):

> An event fired when an entity is tracked by the context, either because it was returned from a tracking query, or because it was attached or added to the context.

Some things to mention.

- The event is **not** fired for [no-tracking queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)
- The event is fired for each entity instance created by the tracking query result set and not already tracked by the context
- The `bool FromQuery` property of the event args is used to distinguish if the event is fired from the tracking query materialization process or via user code (`Attach`, `Add` etc. calls).
- The `EntityEntry Entry` property of the event args gives you access to the entity instance and other related information (basically the same information that you get when calling the non-generic `DbContext.Entry` method)

Comment: You are welcome :) Sorry again for the miscommunication from my end.

Comment: No problem and sorry from here if seeming to be touchy :)